# How can one estimate the number of illegal aliens in the US?

Tags: estimation, modeling, survey

My question, I guess, is really two-fold: #1: What kind of data would a statistician look at, and #2: From that data, how would they extract an estimate of the number of illegal aliens? Estimates of the illegal alien population, I would imagine, present a rather interesting challenge to a statistician. Any survey done would likely rely on an illegal migrant's willingness to be truthful about their status. ICE and CBP data can only account for individuals known or suspected by them to be illegal aliens, but there are potentially others not accounted for.

The Pew Hispanic Center claims to be able to make an estimate using USgovernment data and something called the "residual method" where they are somehow able to take data on foreign-born persons and subtract legal residents, refugees, etc. to arrive at the number of illegal aliens. (source: http://www.pewhispanic.org/2012/12/06/unauthorized-immigrants-11-1-million-in-2011/)

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @Scortchi My question, I guess, is really two-fold: #1: What kind of data would a statistician look at, and #2: From that data, how would they extract an estimate of the number of illegal aliens? Estimates of the illegal alien population, I would imagine, present a rather interesting challenge to a statistician. Any survey done would likely rely on an illegal migrant's willingness to be truthful about their status. ICE and CBP data can only account for individuals known or suspected by them to be illegal aliens, but there are potentially others not accounted for.

Comment: You could also use DACA/DAPA application data.

Comment: By the title, I had thought it is something from the Universe.

Comment: @DeepNorth One of the definitions of "alien" is: "a foreigner, especially one who is not a naturalized citizen of the country where they are living."

Comment: I forgot to say to edit your question with clarifications, rather than make potential answerers  pick through a comment thread.

Comment: # of illegal aliens = # of residents - # of citizens - # of legal aliens. Census has first input, CIS should have the rest. In the future it should be much easier than that with biometric (including facial) recognition, it should be possible to count exact number of people with the borders and their immigration status. only those hiding in the caves would not be counted. otherwise, if you show up anywhere in the streets you'll be picked up by mass surveyllance systems